# How to get dom element content before page is modified

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a chrome extension which could obtain a specified element's content. The problem is that the webpage has some script that will replace the original content with something else.

Let's assume the original HTML is:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

and somehow the page will be change to:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>RUBBISH</p>
</div>
```

before it's displayed.

How can I get the value `bar` before script changes it to `RUBBISH`?

I know there is a value `document_start` for `run_at`, but since the `script` tag is not blocking, and the chrome injected content script will be run before the web page DOM is constructed, how could I possibly can the value `bar`?

Comment: How can the value change before the parent even exits?

Comment: @Ood the webpage's script changes it.for example the page may contain $(document).ready(...). I didn't said it change before DOM exist.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events. I'm still not one hundred percent sure about your question but maybe it helps you.

Comment: @Ood thanks. Or can I detect what script change the element?

Comment: You may be able to track down the function using arguments.callee (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee). But I don't recommend using it.